# Input field validation for non-whitespaces word length Maximum 40

Tags: angularjs, html, validation, angularjs-directive

How to make an input field to type only a non-whitespaces word of size 40 characters? suggest any directive or any other solution?

**Valid input text:** "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo explicari honestatis"

**inValid input text:** "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Loremipsum      LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem justo"

**invalid input** contains a word with size 45 characters without any space

i.e: "LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem"

Comment: ?? Your valid input contains whitespaces which you said was forbidden?

Comment: I guess I know what you intend to do. Your formulation is a little misleading. One would think, that whitespaces are not allowed. You mean only non-whitespaces should be considered for the maximum count of characters, right?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: I make an example for you [see plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rki22FzoUKdDHCPi7ZMI?p=preview)! it should be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could register a `changelistener` on the input field and analyze the entire input every time the user typed something. Subtract the number of whitespaces from the length of the input field value and if the result exceeds 40 characters, delete the last character of the input and notify the user.